# Show data in a View from a Inner Join query in NET Framework MVC project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, inner-join

I'm new to this, so please be verbose in your answer.

In my mvc net framework project ([here](https://github.com/DLGEJ-Entornos/Astrofilm) only for completeness), I would like to show in my Film view (linked with FilmsController[PeliculasController]), the Director of that film.
Directors are stored in Workers(Trabajadores) table, with a relation many to many using the middle table PELI_TRABAJADOR (FILM_WORKER). This table doesn't appear in my Models folder, but in my Films Model I have a ICollection of WORKERS.

I think I have to make a Inner Join query to navigate from FILMS to FILM-WORKERS, WORKERS tables but I don't know where(Model,Controller,new Class..) and how to do it. I'm trying to follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins) documentation. But when I'm creating the query in order to access to WORKERS table I get an error. (FilmsController):

```
 public static void InnerJoinEx()
    {
        var query = from peli in PELICULAS
                    join trabajador in PELICULAS.TRABAJADORES equals //ERROR
    }
```

The error is on PELICULAS.TRABAJADORES is: CS0120: An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'foo'

By using this on my PELICULAS/Details View(FILMS view):

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TRABAJADORES.ToArray()[0])
```

I get all the properties with values of my model TRABAJADORES(WORKERS). How can I get only the value of FullName method? or Name & Surname properties?

Thanks for reading me, sorry for my English and my ignorance about the subject. I will be very grateful in your help.

Comment: What error do you get at `//ERROR HERE` ? That's pretty important in understanding how to help you. Always include the actual error message. *(A hint on how to resolve it: after `PELICULAS.TRABAJADORES`, the `on` keyword is expected, not equals.)*

Comment: I'm trying in /FILMS/Details View do something like this:
`<dl class="dl-horizontal">
   @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TRABAJADORES.Count)
`
And I get the number of Directors for this film. But I don't know how to show the name.

Comment: I wouldn't be able to write an answer with complete code because I don't know enough to fill in the blanks (like the join condition or the projection). For now, I'll say this: it looks like you're trying to use a navigation property. Try `peli.TRABAJADORES` instead. And since the navigation property is already limited the parent records, you can use `from` rather than `join` and the join condition can be avoided.

Comment: peli.TRABAJADORES after in token says: It's not defined in the current context.
I'm not even sure if I could make this function in the FilmsController.. (maybe is in the Model).

Comment: We're past psychic debugging, then. You need to post your class definitions.

Comment: And what about the issue in /Films/Details  as I mention above? Thanks

Comment: Cross that bridge when you get there. Until you know how to get your data and place it in the view model, there's no point in dealing with the view.